# How do i use conditional parameters in Laravel Auth::attempt?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

Using Laravel 4.1.30 I got this following code which test a sign-in attempt via Auth.

```php
//... more codes here ...

$auth = Auth::attempt(array(
    'email'     => Input::get('email'),
    'password'  => Input::get('password'),
    'active'    => 1
), $remember);

if ($auth) {
    //... more codes here ...
}
```

I like to implement a conditional value such as:

```
->active > 0
```

I am using the active (field) as a level of authentication for users signing in. Anything above 0 (zero) should satisfy the next condition.

How can it be done in one statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## tl;dr

You can't do this within the array passed to `Auth::attempt()`, because in the framework it is hard coded to use equality comparison in the generated query.

## Full review

### Framework implementation

The `attempt()` function is implemented in `Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php`.

```php
public function attempt(array $credentials = array(), $remember = false, $login = true)
{
    $this->fireAttemptEvent($credentials, $remember, $login);

    $this->lastAttempted = $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

    // If an implementation of UserInterface was returned, we'll ask the provider
    // to validate the user against the given credentials, and if they are in
    // fact valid we'll log the users into the application and return true.
    if ($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials))
    {
        if ($login) $this->login($user, $remember);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here you can see a call for `$this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);`. The `retrieveByCredentials()` function is implemented in `Illuminate/Auth/DatabaseUserProvider.php`.

```php
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{
    // First we will add each credential element to the query as a where clause.
    // Then we can execute the query and, if we found a user, return it in a
    // generic "user" object that will be utilized by the Guard instances.
    $query = $this->conn->table($this->table);

    foreach ($credentials as $key => $value)
    {
        if ( ! str_contains($key, 'password'))
        {
            $query->where($key, $value);
        }
    }

    // Now we are ready to execute the query to see if we have an user matching
    // the given credentials. If not, we will just return nulls and indicate
    // that there are no matching users for these given credential arrays.
    $user = $query->first();

    if ( ! is_null($user))
    {
        return new GenericUser((array) $user);
    }
}
```

Here you can see that the array you pass to `Auth::attempt()` is processed in a `foreach` and every key-value pairs are added as a `WHERE` clause to the query. Because it done with a `$query->where($key, $value);` call, it is limited to equality comparison.

### Possible solutions

A workaround would be to change this line to something like:

```
$query->where($key, $value['operator'], $value['value']);
```

Then you could restructure the array given to `Auth::attempt()`.

```
$auth = Auth::attempt(array(
    'email' => array(
        'value'    => Input::get('email'),
        'operator' => '='
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'value'    => Input::get('password'),
        'operator' => '='
    ),
    'active' => array(
        'value'    => 0,
        'operator' => '>'
    )
), $remember);
```

The problem with this is that you have to override every other function that uses this array, so you end up with a custom solution. With this effort you could write your own authentication query or do a check on `active` after `Auth::attempt()`.

Comment: My bad, sorry for that totymedli. You're 100% correct

Comment: @deczo Ok, no problem. I also improved it to be more precise.

Comment: Cool solution, I like to propose in addition, that if there are no operator called, it is defaulted to '=' so as to shorten the code even more.

Comment: this should be default behaviour, hardcoding equality operator is bad

Answer (score 4):

**Laravel 8+**

`Auth::attempt` now supports closures

Example to authenticate only if user status is not `suspsended`:

```php
$authenticated = Auth::attempt([
'username' => 'demo-user',
 'password' => 'some-password',
 'status' => function ($query) {
       $query->where('status', '!=', 'suspended');
  }
]);
```

Reference https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/c240972be84573a9c73b8c9a8be472aff94296a8/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php#L127-L129

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively you can also do as fast solution as below

```
$auth = Auth::attempt(array(
        'email'     => Input::get('email'),
        'password'  => Input::get('password'),
    ), $remember);
    if ($auth) {
                $currentUser = Auth::user();
                if (!($currentUser->status > 0)) {
                    return "invalid_credential";
                }
    }
```